# Python: load_pem_private_key is failing to recognize my private key in production

Tags: python, flask, cryptography, github-actions, rsa

Locally, I have an .env file containing a single line RSA key like so:
`PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\ncontentsofkey\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"`

Every 64 characters contains a `\n` to escape new lines.
This key format works locally and allows my Python app to run as intended, the private key is able to load.

The issue begins in Production. I copy and paste the private key one line format into a GitHub Secret, however the EXACT same key and format is throwing back this error:

> ValueError: ('Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format, it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm, or it may be an unsupported key type (e.g. EC curves with explicit parameters).', [<OpenSSLError(code=503841036, lib=60, reason=524556, reason_text=unsupported)>])

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> ValueError: ('Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format, it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm, or it may be an unsupported key type (e.g. EC curves with explicit parameters).', [<OpenSSLError(code=75497580, lib=9, reason=108, reason_text=no start line)>])

As stated in the reason_text, it seems the key format is unsupported and there is no state line? Which leaves me extremely confused because this is working locally, but not in production. In production I am running a venv using the exact same requirements.txt and python version when I test local.

I have added a print statement before the load_pem_private_key() function to see the format of the key, and it prints in the exact same format as my .env file... which works just fine locally:

`"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\ncontentsofkey\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"`

I don't see any difference between the print statements locally and in production to see if the keys are being manipulated somewhere.

Has anyone have had this happen before? I need to store the private key in a single line or else GitHub Actions workflow throws back YAML syntax errors.

Here is the code I am working with, again it works just fine locally but not in production:

```
        now = int(time.time())
        payload = {"iat": now, "exp": now + expiration, "iss": self.id}
        print(self.key)
        # This line below is throwing the error showed above
        encrypted = jwt.encode(payload, key=self.key, algorithm="RS256")

        if isinstance(encrypted, bytes):
            encrypted = encrypted.decode("utf-8")
        return encrypted
```

The print statement in the code above is for debugging purposes.

Any ideas? The cryptography package is throwing the `_handle_key_loading_error` for `load_pem_public_key`

Here is the GitHub workflow:

```
      - name: Deploy secrets
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'release' || github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch' }}
    run:  |
      eval "echo \"$(cat .deployment/secret.yaml)\"" | kubectl apply -f -
    env: 
      GITHUBAPP_KEY: '${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}'
```

Below is deployment file for k8's secret

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: xxx
  namespace: xxx
type: Opaque
stringData:
  GITHUBAPP_KEY: '${GITHUBAPP_KEY}'
```

How GITHUBAPP_KEY is being read in python:

```py
app.config["GITHUBAPP_KEY"] = environ["GITHUBAPP_KEY"]
```

Comment: Please always include your GHA workflow in your question. It's hard to say anything without it.

Comment: @Azeem, you're right, I added it in, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Thanks! Try `eval "echo -e ..."`.

Comment: When I do eval "echo -e \"$(cat  .... ", it throws a YAML syntax error about parsing the secret. I have also wrapped the GitHub secret context around single quotes but it's still complaining.

Comment: How's that key being used in `.deployment/secret.yaml`?

Comment: @Azeem, updated my post to see original file.

Comment: To avoid any formatting problems that may be caused by the combination of the PEM encoding and the .env file, you could simply use [`load_der_private_key()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.load_der_private_key) and import the DER encoded key instead of the PEM encoded one. To do this, the .env file must only contain `contentsofkey` (*without* any line breaks). This must be Base64 decoded and passed to `load_der_private_key()`.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to emulate your scenario. Creating a variable directly with the single line key worked fine. However, when read from the YAML file via `yaml` module or `os.environ`, it contained `\\n` instead of `\n`. I was getting the same deserialization failure error with `\\n`. Replacing these with `\n` fixed the issue and `jwt.encode()` started to work fine after that.

In the following CLI example, `key` is a variable that has directly been assigned and `key1` has been read from the YAML file (observe the escape characters and the difference in sizes):

```py
>>> key
'-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nKEY\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'
>>> key1
'-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\\nKEY\\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'
>>> len(key)
1650
>>> len(key1)
1652
```

Here's the working GHA workflow:

```yaml
name: python_jwt

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Create secret.yaml
      env:
        GITHUBAPP_KEY: '${{ secrets.TEST_PRIVATE_KEY }}'
      shell: bash
      run: |
        cat > secret.yaml << 'EOF'
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Secret
        metadata:
          name: xxx
          namespace: xxx
        type: Opaque
        stringData:
          GITHUBAPP_KEY: '${GITHUBAPP_KEY}'
        EOF
        eval "echo \"$(cat secret.yaml)\"" > secret-new.yaml
        ls -l secret*

    - name: Set GITHUBAPP_KEY env var
      run: echo "GITHUBAPP_KEY=$(yq -e '.stringData.GITHUBAPP_KEY' secret-new.yaml)" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"

    - name: JWT
      shell: python
      run: |
        import os, time, jwt
        key = os.environ['GITHUBAPP_KEY'].encode().replace(b'\\n', b'\n')
        print(f'{len(key)} | {key}')
        now = int(time.time())
        payload = {"iat": now, "exp": now, "iss": "123456"}
        encrypted = jwt.encode(payload, key=key, algorithm="RS256")
        print(f'encrypted: {encrypted}')
```

The `secrets.TEST_PRIVATE_KEY` is one single line private key like this:

```bash
HEADER\nKEY\nFOOTER
```

The `KEY` part is a continuous string with no newlines. The only newlines are: one after `HEADER` and the other before `FOOTER`.

Output:

[image: output]

You need to verify this on your side and figure out the actual key being passed to `jwt.encode()`.

Comment: Azeem, if you python print your key without the extra //n, does the key come out in the correct format? i.e new line every 64 characters. I have yet to test your method, will give that a go today or tomorrow.

Comment: @yungpeso: I stored the key as a secret in one single line i.e. `HEADER\nKEY\nFOOTER`. The `KEY` part is one continuous string i.e. only two newlines: one after `HEADER` and another before `FOOTER`. I was trying to emulate your scenario based on the information included in your question and its comments. In your Python snippet, the loading of `self.key` part is missing so I loaded it from the YAML directly to keep it simple; and that may not be the case as you're most probably be getting it as an env vars in the container passed via k8s manifests. Sure, do verify everything on your side.

Comment: sorry for the delay. I can verify they self.key is getting printed in the bytes format:

b'-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nkey here\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n'

Comment: Does your private key in secrets have an \n every 64 characters? Making it one line? Also which python package is your import jwt reading from?

Comment: @yungpeso: Updated my answer to address the key format. Regarding Python package, I'm using the preinstalled one and `import jwt` just works there. It may already have `pyjwt` there but I'm not sure. You may provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with everything in it to show your exact use case. You may omit the secret and provide it as an env var. That'll be much easier to iterate over and find out the exact issue you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried encoding the key to base64 and storing it like that? Just don't forget to decode it when used.

Answer (score 0):

Github Actions secret cannot hold data with newline, so secrets like PEM key needs to be encoded into base64 form, and decoded when used. [Ref](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions#storing-base64-binary-blobs-as-secrets)

Here's what you should do

1. Encode your key into base64 form first. You can do this with online converter or with CLI.
2. Update the base64-encoded value into your secret.
3. In your Python code, decode the base64 value, you will get the original PEM key value. Pass this decoded value to the function.

Give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related to how the private key is being handled in the GitHub Actions workflow. The YAML syntax and variable handling in workflows can sometimes cause subtle issues.

First, let's simplify the GitHub Actions workflow by directly passing the private key as a string without using the `eval` command. Update the workflow as follows:

```yaml
- name: Deploy secrets
  if: ${{ github.event_name == 'release' || github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch' }}
  run: kubectl create secret generic xxx --from-literal=GITHUBAPP_KEY="${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}"
```

Now, in your Python script, retrieve the secret using `os.environ`:

```py
import os

# ...

app.config["GITHUBAPP_KEY"] = os.environ["GITHUBAPP_KEY"]
```

Ensure that the private key is stored as a single line in the GitHub secret, just like you've shown in your .env file.

If the issue persists, there might be subtle differences between the local environment and the production environment. You can try the following steps:

1. **Check for Line Endings:**
   Ensure that the line endings in the GitHub secret are consistent. Sometimes, different systems may use different line endings (e.g., Unix vs. Windows).
2. **Check for Leading/Trailing Spaces:**
   Verify that there are no leading or trailing spaces in the private key when stored in the GitHub secret.
3. **Explicitly Specify Encoding:**
   When decoding the private key in your Python script, explicitly specify the encoding as UTF-8:

   ```py
   app.config["GITHUBAPP_KEY"] = os.environ["GITHUBAPP_KEY"].encode("utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")
   ```

   This ensures that any special characters are properly interpreted.
4. **Debugging:**
   Add additional debug statements in your Python script to print the length and content of the private key before it's passed to `load_pem_private_key()`. This can help identify any unexpected characters or formatting.

By addressing these potential differences and simplifying the GitHub Actions workflow, you should be able to resolve the issue. If the problem persists, it might be worth considering alternative ways to store and retrieve the private key or examining the environment configurations in your production setup more closely.