# Google Cloud Run: Cannot authenticate with github ci-cd, ValueError: Could not deserialize key data, using gcloud auth login --cred-file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions, google-cloud-run

I was trying to deploy my project using github actions, i have ci-cd.yml like this :

```
name: CI/CD Project
on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:          
      - name: Code Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: create credentials
        working-directory: backend
        run: |-
          echo > credentials.txt && echo "${{secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}}" >> credentials.txt
```

My secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in github secrets is a json like:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "xxx",
  "private_key_id": "xxx",
  "private_key": "xxx",
  "client_email": "github-actions@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "xxx",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/github-actions%40xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}
```

In my window, with Google Cloud SDK Shell, I logon with gcloud auth login --cred-file=[my credentials file path] and it successfully.

When github perform action, i got error:

```
Run gcloud auth login --cred-file=credentials.txt
  gcloud auth login --cred-file=credentials.txt
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e ***0***
  env:
    CLOUDSDK_METRICS_ENVIRONMENT: github-actions-setup-gcloud
    CLOUDSDK_METRICS_ENVIRONMENT_VERSION: 1.1.1
ERROR: gcloud crashed (ValueError): ('Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format, it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm, or it may be an unsupported key type (e.g. EC curves with explicit parameters).', [<OpenSSLError(code=503841036, lib=60, reason=524556, reason_text=unsupported)>])
```

Note that my secrets was added successfully.

Comment: What does the value of `private_key` look like? Single line?

Comment: The error is telling you that it cannot parse `credentials.txt`. Something is wrong with the file. Invalid JSON contents, incorrect line ending (LF versus CRLF), etc. Store the file as an artifact, download it to your local computer, and analyze it.

Comment: Please check if there any whitespace on the txt file or not.

Comment: I deleted all whitespaces, tab, newline and pushed again, but still error, I also cat file, value is perfect.

Comment: @Azeem It looks like:  `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nabcd\nabcd\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n`

Comment: @CườngNguyễnMạnh: Try removing those intermediate `\n` from the private key i.e. `HEADER\nKEY\nFOOTER`. Yesterday, I observed a similar issue in this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77804343/7670262) with the same error.

Comment: @Azeem I found the error, I perform : `echo 
 "${{secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}}" >> credentials.txt` , where that secrets is ok, but the  result of `cat credentials.txt`, all characters `\\` was deny, so my private key looks like: -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----nabcdnabcdn-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: @CườngNguyễnMạnh: Good to hear that. In shell, i.e. under the `run` sections, always use single quote for `${{...}}` expressions.

Comment: @Azeem thank you for solution, can you push your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ERROR: gcloud crashed (ValueError): ('Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format, it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm, or it may be an unsupported key type (e.g. EC curves with explicit parameters).', [<OpenSSLError(code=503841036, lib=60, reason=524556, reason_text=unsupported)>])

Apparently, the `private_key` format is not correct. You need to verify and fix that.

Also, make sure to use single quotes around `${{...}}` expressions. Depending on the [shell](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell) being used, in your case it's Bash (`ubuntu-latest`), the expression may contain characters expandable by the shell which may not be desirable.

---

Apart from that, `echo > credentials.txt` is redundant. You can skip it altogether and dump credentials directly like this:

```bash
echo '${{ secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS }}' > credentials.txt
```

You might want to use the `.json` extension instead of `.txt` as the contents of the file are a valid JSON:

```
credentials.txt => credentials.json
```